# How to disable videos on chromedriver selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to disable all kinds of videos on chromedriver because they slow down automation and consume bandwith? I'm not asking how to stop autoplay videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use run ChromeDriver with an extension like:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-no-buffer-stop-au/afgfpcfjdgakemlmlgadojdfnejkpegd

Chrome does not have a standard switch to turn off video loading, except autoplay switch that you've mentioned:
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Best regards,
PM